# Adding Foreign Key to routes

Tags: mysql, node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I have my parent table "Users" and child table "Contacts". I have added a foreign key to my Contacts table to link the information added back to the Users table. How can I add it in routes so it can create it automatically through postman when posting a contact.

Users(parent table model)

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require("../database/db.js")

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Users = sequelize.define('users', {
        user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    });
    return Users
}
```

contacts(child table model)

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Contact = sequelize.define('profile_contacts', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        phone: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        linkedin_profile: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
        fk_user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        }
    });


    return Contact
```

contact(routes)

```
var express = require("express")
var router = express.Router()
const db = require('../database/db.js');
const Contact = db.Contacts;
var User = db.Users;

// get all jobs
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    Contact.findAll()
      .then(contacts => {
          res.json(contacts)
      })
      .catch(err => {
          res.send('error: ' + err)
      })
})

// Add job
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    if(!req.body.phone,
       !req.body.linkedin_profile) {
        res.status(400)
        res.json({
            error: "Bad Data"
        })
    } else {
       Contact.create(req.body)
        .then(() => {
            res.send("Contact Added")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send("Error: " + err)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, not understanding what you need?